# SQL Server - Partition by or Row num or Subquery - Assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the below problem.

I am trying to see how often a customer has requested Re-Activation of their Internet account.

The problem is, we capture a limited set of data to group on.
So my data set is below.

I am trying to Count from the first time a Re-Activation request was created until the First time it was COMPLETED, once it has been completed finish the count of days it took for the request to complete and count the number of NON COMPLETIONS and SENT statuses which occurred between that time.

Below is an image of the sample data as well as the sql for the table.
Hope somebody can provide a little help.
(using SQL server 2005 compatibility)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kwxF.jpg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GjGk.jpg)

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
Identifier varchar(20)NOT NULL
,CreatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL
,CompletedDate DATETIME NOT NULL
,SN_Type varchar(20) NOT NULL
,SN_Status varchar(20) NOT NULL
)
;


INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160729','20160805','Re-Activattion','SENT');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160810','20160810','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160812','20160812','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160811','20160811','Re-Activattion','COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('64074558792','20160811','20160813','Re-Activattion','N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ('61030203647','20160427','20160427','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20160427','20160427','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20160422','20160422','Re-Activattion', 'N-CO');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203647','20170210','20170210','Re-Activattion', 'COMP');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203688','20170409','20170210','Re-Activattion', 'SENT');
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES('61030203699','20170409','20170210','De-Activattion', 'COMP');
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the desired results.  Showing the sample data as a table would also be helpful.

Comment: Please post expected results as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, sorry thought I had attached it. It is an image as i believe its the clearest way I could explain it.

Comment: If memory serves, 2005 does not support the over clause.

Comment: What are my alternatives?